# Deseralize protobuff byte array in Python

Tags: java, python, protocol-buffers

I have a java end point which returns a Protobuf ByteArray from some other component. I am hitting that end point from python to retrieve data from it.

Problem :- I am not able to deserialize the protobuf byte array on python side.
So I am looking for a exact way to parse protobuf byte array to readable form in python.

Comment: Welcome, Jai. What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: I am new to python and I don't know how to deserailize protobyf object in python. I tried using "import base64" but it has thrown error stating that "invalid continuation type".

Comment: OK. Step 1 is to get a protobuf library, read how to use it, and try it. Generally we get python libraries from pypi.org, in this case, https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/

Comment: Hi @Jai were you able to find the solution to it? I am also facing this issue. There is a method fromByteArray in java but I am unable to find a similar method in python.

Comment: @user812142 yes, I am able to solve it via different approach